# Searching database for existing record problems

Tags: database, delphi, validation

I'm making a program which has a registration page and saved the data to a database. I'm trying to verify the  username so that there won't be people with the same username.. The username is also the primary key in my database.. When I click the submit button the program either just freezes or give me the following  error message: "Exception class EOIeException with  message 'The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field that contain duplicate data, remove index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again"

I am using  the following code to search if the edit box text appears in the database and if it does that it should display a message box.. But instead it gives me the error as said above.

```
with dmPredictGame do
    while NOT tblUserInfo.EOF do
    begin
      tblUserInfo.First;
      if Uppercase(edtUsername.Text) = tblUserInfo['Username'] then
        begin
          MessageDlg('The username "' + edtUsername.Text + '" already exists!', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
          edtusername.SetFocus;
          exit;
        end
      else
        tblUserInfo.Next;
        tblUserInfo.Close
    end;
```

Comment: move tblUserInfo.First; before While, rethink your strategy

Comment: As mentioned, the `First` statement needs to go before your loop, otherwise the dataset cursor keeps going back to the first record every iteration. Also, why not just do a simple query `select * from users where username = [username]`?

Comment: If I do that it gives me an error on the while NOT line.. Error is   "undeclared identifier: 'tblUserInfo'"  and another error on the same line of code saying "'DO'  expected but identifier 'EOF' found"

Comment: "gives me an error" Probably because you've moved tblUserinfo.First outside the "with dmPredictGame ..." block.  Btw, avoid "with ..." constructs like the plague.

Comment: No. I moved the tblUserInfo between the "with dmPredictGame"  and the while..

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  The "with" needs a begin ... end around all the code you want it to apply to.  Without that, when you moved the tblUserInfo.First, the "with ..." would apply only to that statement, not the "while ..." block which follows.  Which just goes to show how easy it is to get tripped up by "with".

Comment: If the user name is a primary key, why not just attempt to use it in a transaction? If it fails the transaction will be rolled back and you'll know the user name was already taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search using your method, be sure to put the `First` outside the loop, otherwise you'll keep starting over, and never finish:

```
// Go to the beginning
tblUserInfo.First;
while NOT tblUserInfo.EOF do
begin
  // Set both to upper so they match
  // Use FieldByName (it's not an array)
  if Uppercase(edtUsername.Text) = Uppercase(tblUserInfo.FieldByName('Username').AsString) then
  begin
    MessageDlg('The username "' + edtUsername.Text + '" already exists!', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    edtUsername.SetFocus;
    Exit;
  end;
  tblUserInfo.Next;
end;
```

However, for searches, you should consider using `Locate`:

```
if tblUserInfo.Locate('UserName', edtUserName.Text, [loCaseInsensitive]) then
begin
  // Username exists
end;
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't try using Locate.. Feel kinda like a idiot now haha.. Works perfectly now.  Thank you Markus